# html5 Audio - pitch bend without web audio API

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

I've been looking online for an alternative or polyfill to the web audio API. Specifically i'm looking for a way to pitch bend Audio and i'm thrown off by the Web Audio API as it's not supported in IE. There's a lot of other web audio api features i'd love to use but the pitch bend one is critical so not sure if there is a library out there that can achieve this with html5 audio or if it's even possible to?

This leads me to ask also if anyone would know if Microsoft are planning on releasing support for the Web Audio API for IE11 anytime?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, IE will not get support for WebAudio.  But Edge supports WebAudio.